# How to run cron job on 29th of every month?

Tags: cron

Is it possible to write a single cron expression which runs on the 29<sup>th</sup> day of every month **OR** the last day if the month has only 28 days (e.g. February)?

Comment: What is the link with java?

Comment: This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) page tells you all you need to know about cron expressions

Comment: Consider scheduling for the 28th and the 29th and using a (shell script) wrapper to decide whether the program really should be run.

Comment: You can do last day of the month 0 0 12 L 1/1 ? *

Answer (score 2):

Single cron syntax is not possible. You can do last day of the month

```
0 0 12 L 1/1 ? *.
```

It will trigger last day of every month.

```
0 0 12 29 1/1 ? *.
```

If you trigger like this you will miss non leap year February.